# How to access document/DOM in background.js?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, browser-extension

I'm trying to access the DOM in my background script to create a canvas element. How do I access the DOM in background.js in manifest v3? I know it's accessible in v2.

I'm creating this element as part of `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()`, which is an API method specific to background.js

```
chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(tab.windowId, { format: "png" }, function(dataUrl) {
            (console.log("chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab() called"))
            if (!canvas) {
                canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            ...
```

I get an error currently: `Error handling response: ReferenceError: document is not defined at chrome-extension://.../background.js`

I tried passing the document to background script from content script like this:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({document: document}, function(response) {})
```

but the passed document isn't an object and doesn't have normal DOM methods like `createElement`

Comment: It's not possible. Use `OffscreenCanvas` instead.

Comment: @wOxxOm darn. And thanks, I wasn't aware of `OffscreenCanvas`. It looks like it has limited browser support atm- firefox requires user permission(maybe that's solved with a simple permission request in my extension popup). But right now, I'm thinking it might be easier to go back to manifest v2